# Can a question with 800 views, 7 answers, 20+comments and 9 votes be still counted as vague

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked a question few days back, which was very clear in its statement. The question was regarding compiler and definitely can be answered and was answered pretty well by the fellow programmers. But, still the question was closed as unreal, ambiguous, and vague. I requested for the reopen but it stated that I need 5 votes. Since the question was closed after more than 2 days, everyone had read it; so no one considered to re-visit and upvote it(may be many of them didnt value it that much). And Now, the question is closed and cant be seen so how can i expect 5 votes.

The question i am talking about is this [ONE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104710/compilers-are-only-for-developers-right). Can this be reopened or still lacks substance to be live at Programmers.

It might not be a great question but still holds a minute value.

Comment: whoever downvoted please explain so that i can learn what should not be asked here and where i am lacking.

Comment: lol....one more downvote without explanation. I will ask for deletion

Comment: FYI, as you might have seen in the other questions - votes on this *meta* site, don't affect your reputation on the *main* PE site.

Comment: Ya i noticed that. Basically i was trying to know what was downvoting for ? Was it in disapproval or was something wrong with the question content

Comment: As the [FAQ](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences) says, downvotes here often simply mean disagreement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before I address your specific question, it's important to note that the level of activity a question gets has no bearing on community moderation: there is no "safe" zone for bad questions just because they're popular.

Stack Exchange only works insofar as it attracts experts: questions that don't demonstrate a base understanding or preparation for a question give experts—who we need to answer questions—the impression that the site isn't worth their time. So a really bad question like "What's your favorite programming cartoon?", while wildly popular because it has a low barrier to entry, will be closed every single time.

Instead, look to [the FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) for guidance or like you've done here, ask a question on meta asking why a question was closed.

To get to your specific question, I can see why 5 members of the community closed it: you provided a basic summary of your understanding of what a compiler is, and then asked people to confirm or deny it. That's not *really* what we're shooting for here. You can confirm whether your understanding of a compiler is correct by looking it up on Wikipedia.

There *is* a potentially interesting question there: "can compilers be used by non-developers?" with a subtextual question, "when would compilers be used by non-developers?" I've revised your question to highlight those questions and reopened it.

The one thing that's preventing this question from being really great is *why* you're asking. Answers provided are survey-level stuff that could easily be answered by Wikipedia, but where Stack Exchange really shines is when we start solving your specific question.

If you can revise your question to specify what problem you're solving by knowing if non-developers use compilers, it'd go from being a okay, but open-ended question to a great, concrete question that's really the best of what Programmers has to offer.

Comment: hmm....may be you are correct, the question earlier wasn't put in the right context. I have seen your edit and this was my intent to know whether the compilers are used out of the scope of developers, but had wrong choice of words and sentence. This answer seems perfect making me understand popularity doesn't count for valuable question. Thanks for the explanation, eiditing and reopening.